# Jenkinsfile: permission denied when running sh step in Docker container

Tags: shell, docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have trouble running a simple `Jenkinsfile` - e.g.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'ssh-slave' } 
    stages {
        stage('Shell Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Hello World"'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The logfiles of Jenkins on the master show that the container was started successfully but the build job crashes with a message like

```
sh: 1: /home/jenkins/workspace/pipeline@tmp/durable-34c21b81/script.sh: Permission denied
```

Here are some additional things that we configured / figured out:

1. We are running the agent on a VM with RHEL
2. We are using the [Docker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) for Jenkins to start / manage the containers on a separate Jenkins agent
3. We are spinning up the Docker container using the `Connect with ssh` method in the Jenkins plugin and use the [jenkinsci/ssh-slave Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/ssh-slave/)
4. Jenkins is using the `root` user in the Docker container (at least all files within `/home/jenkins/...` are created as root
5. When we add a `sleep` step into the pipeline and `docker exec...` into the running container, we cannot execute a simple shell script as root, if we are trying to run it with `./script.sh` (even if we set proper file mode with `chmod +x script.sh` before) - we also get `sh: 1: permission denied`. But we can run the script, if we use `sh script.sh`
6. The `root` user inside the Docker container has a `bash` - whereas Jenkins is trying to run the script with `sh`.
7. The error occurs no matter whether we check the `run privileged` flag in the Docker plugin's template configuration or not

Things we already tried, but didn't work

1. Changing the login shell of the `root` user in the Docker container to `/bin/sh`
2. Providing a shebang in the `sh` step, à la

   ```
   sh '''#!/bin/sh
   echo "hello world"
   '''
   ```
3. Setting the shell executor to `/bin/sh` in the Jenkins global configuration
4. Changing the `Dockerfile` of the ssh-slave Docker image in such a way that the `ENTRYPOINT` does not run a `bash` script, but runs `/bin/sh` at the end

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The `script.sh` is generated by the durable workflow plugin and then executed as a long living process on a node. It is going to be a bit difficult to figure out. Which users are running what? What SSH credential/user are the agents being started with? Are you guys using volume mounts or anything? Is there a way to provide a minimal example here?

Comment: Have you tried to use the `jenkins` user to log into the container? Because that user is set up in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-ssh-slave/blob/master/Dockerfile). Still, I'm wondering how a root login currently works (because of `PermitRootLogin no`).

Comment: @StephenKing - we "logged in" to the container via `docker exec -it ...`, so it was no ssh login or something. That worked for us. I also think that Jenkins ran the jobs as `root` in the container, since all files in the `workspace` were owned by `root`. Solution of the problem is below - thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that `/home/jenkins` in the container was mounted with `noexec`:

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/rhel-var on /home/jenkins type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Underlying issue was that the `/var` on the underlying host was mounted with `noexec` (`/var` is where all the container files reside...):

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/rhel-var on /var type xfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

So the solution to this problem was to mount `/var` as executeable on the host via

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /var
```

that solved the issue for us.

Comment: You lost me.  I don't understand this answer.  It looks like you didn't modify the  Jenkinsfile.  There was something external you had to change?  Where did you perform this this "mount" command?

Comment: I performed this mount command on the machine where the Jenkins jobs are running. No, I had not got to modify anything in the Jenkinsfile. A `sh` step in the Jenkinsfile generates a small shell script, which is copied to some temp folder in the workspace of the job. In most cases, this is some directory in `/var`. Within this directory, this shell script is executed, when the `sh` step is run. Since `/var` was mounted as `noexec`, this wasn't possible, so the step failed. Hope this makes things clearer.