# docker permission denied in Jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have been breaking my head over this problem the past few hours. My setup is as follows:

- Running Ubuntu 19.10 hosting docker

Running this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    command: --httpPort=80 --httpsPort=443 --httpsKeyStore=/var/jenkins_ssl/jenkins.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=very-secret-password
    build: .
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 50000:50000
      - 443:443
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ~/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - ~/jenkins-ssl:/var/jenkins_ssl
      - ~/app_config/:/var/app_config/
      - ~/app_logs/:/var/app_logs/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
```

The host has the group docker with id 998. My Dockerfile for the jenkins container is as follows:

```
USER root
ARG DOCKER_GID=998
RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

However, when I try to build something in a Jenkins job, the following error pops up:

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/cicd-test-backend@tmp/durable-79b7d7d6/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/cicd-test-backend@tmp/durable-79b7d7d6/script.sh: docker: Permission denied

script returned exit code 127
```

The build stage is:

```
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('localhost:5000') {
                        def image = docker.build("url-shortener-backend:${env.BUILD_ID}")

                        image.push()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Can anyone spot what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I was running docker in a virtual machine. A similar "permission denied" problem occured. Restarting virtual machine did work. I still don't know what caused it. Try restarting your pc.

Comment: @Mansur Thanks, but I am running this on a DigitalOcean droplet, restarting does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Did you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47191469/jenkinsfile-permission-denied-when-running-sh-step-in-docker-container